How To Convert a 2D Viewport Point to a 3D World Space Coordinate in Unreal Engine 4.27
I'm new to Unreal Engine (4.27) and attempting to recreate a project I started in jMonkey in Unreal Engine. The project is a side-scroller game with 3D elements (think Little Big Planet or the side-scroller levels in Crash Bandicoot) where the player can place and destroy blocks at the mouse cursor's location. But I'm have trouble getting the mouse's coordinates in the 3D world space.
NOTE: In the 3D world space, I'm using the X-axis as the horizontal axis (X), the Z- axis as the vertical axis (Y), and the Y-axis as depth (Z). I'm also using a perspective camera with a 90 degree Field of View.
Initially my idea was to split up the viewport into 4 quadrants so that (0,0) is in the center of the screen and, if the viewport size was 1021x685, the top right-hand corner is (510.5, 342.5) and the lower left-hand corner is (-510.5,-342.5), then get the mouse coordinates from that and add it to the camera's 3D world space coordinates along the player's Y-axis.
So converting (MouseX, MouseY) to ((CameraX + MouseX), PlayerY, (CameraZ + MouseY)).
But that didn't work because, as you get further from the camera's center, the blocks get more squished together and never actually reach the edge of the screen. So I experimented a bit with a few different solutions until I just started hard-coding numbers and found that for a 1021x685 window, I need to multiply the MouseX and MouseY coordinates by 1.33 before adding them to the Camera's world space location to accurately convert them from 2D to 3D.
THE PROBLEM: I need to know where that 1.33 comes from because, if I change the window size, then I need to change that 1.33 to another number (For example: a 547x647 requires multiplication by 2.5). I've seen similar questions, but the solutions either don't work for me, or don't make sense because they use variables with no explanation of where their values come from. So I'm stuck.
The values I know are:

Mouse X and Y in the 2D viewport
The camera's location in the 2D viewport (0, 0)
The camera's location in the 3D Worldspace (110, 960, 265.275)
The camera's Field of View (90 degrees)
The player's location in the 3D Worldspace
The Viewport's size (1021x685 currently)
The Viewport's scale (0.633625 for a 1021x685 viewport)

Also, I'm including my blueprint for getting the 2D mouse coordinates, if that helps.
blueprint:

You may want to ask this over on the [gamedev.se] site.

There's a node for that: "Get Player Controller" -> "Get Hit Result Under Cursor by Channel". It's basically a raycast, will return a hit point on the nearest surface behind the cursor.
The output is a hit result just like in "Trace By Channel" nodes. If you right-click and split the Hit Result, it will include the hit position, among other useful data.
example blueprint
